# Flutter IconButton IconColor OnHover (not hoverColor) on Windows Desktop app

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I'm trying to change the color of the icon itself onHover instead of the splash(?)Circle thing around it,

```
IconButton(
onPressed: () {},
hoverColor:
Colors.green,
icon: const Icon(
Icons.edit)),
```

is there a way to do it, I'm new to flutter, but I have background in java/python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the Icon, you have to rely on a parameter, `_isHovered` for instance, which will be updated when the mouse enter the Icon region.

I see 2 options here, either using a `MouseRegion` + `IconButton`, or you can use an `InkWell` + `Icon` as previously suggested.

**Full example for option 1:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isHovered = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter app'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _isHovered = true;
            });
          },
          onExit: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _isHovered = false;
            });
          },
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: _isHovered ? Colors.green[700] : null)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**For option 2 using `InkWell`,** replace the previous `build` method by:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Flutter app'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        onHover: (hovered) {
          setState(() {
            _isHovered = hovered;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.edit, color: _isHovered ? Colors.green[700] : null),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The difference I see here is the appearance of the button when hovered, the Icon will be green but the hover regions are not the same size. But this can be easily tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `isIconHovered` like this:

```
 bool isIconHovered = false;
```

then instead of `IconButton` use `InkWell` :

```
InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          onHover: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isIconHovered = value;
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: isIconHovered ? Colors.green : null,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Note:** in order to make hover work in `InkWell`, you have to call `onTap` too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but when I hover, it doesn't change the color

Comment: could you please update you question with my answer?

Comment: where are you testing this? on web?

Comment: on windows desktop application.

Comment: @B-DK I updated my answer, some how on desktop app you have to use onTap and onHover together in order to make it work.